# У меня есть пнг, и я хочу создать файл в репозитории github, который будет в себе иметь этот пнг

Tags: python, github

У меня есть файл cam.png, и я хочу поместить этот файл в репозиторий на github, я использую PyGitGub

```
from github import Github

TOKEN='мой токен'
g=Github('TOKEN')

repo= g.get_user().get_repo('db')

with open('cam.png', encoding='cp1251') as file:
    repo.crete_file('cam.png', 'New Png!', file)
```

Но мне выдаёт выдаёт AssertionError. Можно ли вообще так делать? Или нужно по другому?

Comment: Глупый вопрос: а что за кодировка может быть у файлов изображений?

Comment: Честно говоря и сам не  знаю, перед тем как выложить вопрос облазил интернет в поисках информации, ну где то там услышал про кодировку, а в "type" нашего файла, была кодировка "cp1251"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо CrazyElf, с помощью кодировки 'rb' (я не до конца понял), и вправду можно передавать изображение в байтах. В мой код я добавил:

```
x=file.read()
repo.crete_file('cam.png', 'New Png!', x)
```

Comment: Это не кодировка, а режим чтения. Параметр этот у функции `open` называется `mode`, но его название можно пропускать, если это второй параметр.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку файл с картинкой это двоичный файл, открывать его нужно соответственно в двоичном режиме:

```
with open('cam.png', 'rb') as file:
```

По умолчанию питон открывает файлы на чтение в текстовом режиме. Кодировка применима только к текстовым файлам, двоичные файлы читаются "как есть", байт в байт.

Comment: Возьму на заметку, на вот проблему оно не исправило :)

Comment: Возможно сам pygit не поддерживает bytes?